# Get the id of the last updated record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I am able to get the last inserted id using `$this->db->insert_id();` in codeigniter, is there any way that I can get the id of the last updated record? I tried it with the same i.e. `$this->db->insert_id();` but it doesn't work (returns 0 instead).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Codeigniter doesn't support that. I had to do this:

```
$updated_id = 0;

// get the record that you want to update
$this->db->where(array('vrnoa'=>$data['vrnoa'], 'etype' => 'sale'));
$query = $this->db->get('StockMain');

// getting the Id
$result = $query->result_array();
$updated_id = $result[0]['stid'];

// updating the record
$this->db->where(array('vrnoa'=>$data['vrnoa'], 'etype' => 'sale'));
$this->db->update('StockMain',$data);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

this will give only inserted id. For getting the updated row id you can add a column as lastmodified (timestamp) and update this column with current timestamp everytime you run the update query. After your update query just run this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM StockMain ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1');  
$result = $query->result_array();
```

You will get the id in the result set.

Comment: Doesn't work if multiple users doing the update / same operation.

Comment: its a guess, and not satisfy every situation like high usage of the application

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it shortest

```
$where  =   array('vrnoa'=>$data['vrnoa'], 'etype' => 'sale');
```

//Update the record

```
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update('StockMain',$data);
```

//Get the record

```
$this->db->where($where);
return $this->db->get('StockMain')->row()->stid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the id which your using in where clause for update

```
function Update($data,$id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('update_tbl',$data);
        return $id; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a codeigniter , and MY_MODEL an extend version.This was one of the bottlneck this how i got a relfe.

```
  function update_by($where = array(),$data=array())
  {
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->update($this->_table,$data);
        return $this->db->get($this->_table)->row()->id; //id must be exactly the name of your table primary key
  }
```

call this Updates plus get the updated id. kinda overkill to run a query twice i guess but so do all the aboves.

how you call ?

```
 $where = array('ABC_id'=>5,'DEF_ID'=>6);
 $data =  array('status'=>'ACCEPT','seen_status' =>'SEEN');
 $updated_id= $this->friends->update_by($where,$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  //update
    public function update($table, $where, $data)
    {
        // get the record that you want to update
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get($table);

        // getting the Id
        $row = array_values($query->row_array());
        $updated_id = $row[0];

        // updating the record
        $updated_status = $this->db->update($table, $data, $where);

        if($updated_status):
            return $updated_id;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    }
```